# open outlook without knowing the exact file path

Tags: .net, vb.net

is there a way in vb.net to open microsoft outlook without knowing the file path exactly?

different versions of outlook use different file locations, then you have to worry about the program files and program files(x86). is there a way to just launch outlook using the system.diagnostics.process.start("..") without the file path?

i dont want to have to test folders:

```
If Folder_Exists("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12") Then
If Folder_Exists("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11") Then
```

thanks

Comment: As far as I know the Outlook exe directory should be on the system path. Shelling "Outlook" should start it???

Comment: thanks dude -- if you want to mark the answer ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the Outlook exe directory should be on the system path. Shelling "Outlook" should start it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Outlook path is exported, so running OUTLOOK.EXE as command (try Windows+R and executing it to make sure) should execute OutLook right away. To know which path is OutLook in, I don't know if Windows has something like Linux's *which* command.

Comment: Well Windows shell has no which command, but here's a batch replacement if anyone is interested: http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2004/11/equivalent_of_which_in_windows.html

Comment: I don't know, I don't like **OutLook** and I don't use it (same goes for Windows). Write it as you want :)

Answer (score 2):

It is on the system PATH so

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("outlook")
```

You can also start outlook and launch a new email in one go

```
Process.Start("mailto:me@gmail.com?subject=HelloWorld")
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is normally in the system PATH environment variable.

You can use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start with UseShellExecute = true to start it.

(Excuse my C#)

```cs
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "outlook", UseShellExecute = true }
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)
```